# .htaccess conflict between two rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

in my website two rewrite rule are conflicting with each other
i have url for my users like= http://twekr.com/sam
and all my website pages open like http://twekr.com/login

now here is htaccess file rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user=$1
```

Now only this rule works because its loaded first =

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

And if i put profile rewrite rule above

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user=$1 (then this works)
```

and this doesnt

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d (does not work)
```

What is the problem in htaccess rule?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for presence of `.php` file before adding `.php` extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: yeah i have checked every file and url

Comment: Not sure what that comment is for. Did this rule not work? If not then provide all the details.